# In C# standalone app without DB how do I schedule a job with persistence (Quartz.net without DB?)

Tags: c#, .net, persistence, quartz.net, job-scheduling

I'm am working on a .net C# standalone application without a database and i need to trigger a daily/weekly task in the application. i found the Quartz.net library but it seems that it can persist the job store without using a DB (The application/machine can be switched off but i still want the job scheduling data to be saved). Do you know of a way to persist in a file of maybe another way to implement it?
Also i need an option to set the trigger time interval values at run time

thanks!

Comment: `while (true) { Thread.Sleep(...); }`?

Answer (score 0):

Implement a new IJobStore that stores the data however you choose. If you have particular difficulties with this please provide more details about the specific problem.

Comment: The problem here is that if i want to implement a FileJobStore I have to implement 56(!) methods of this interface :/

Comment: Well yes, briefly looking at the documentation I see that there are many elements and I can understand the need for most of them. If you think that's too much unnecessary work there are alternative libraries you could use instead - I hesitate to make any recommendations but I don't see many other paths you could take.